# static qt dialog windows not possible?

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, static-members

it seems that whenever I try to "store" a qt dialog screen into a static variable the program crashes. (With a debug error complaining that a QPaintDevice can't be created before the QMainApplication).

As this error happened before the main was loop was entered I took it the problem was with the static variables. (Well and it was the only thing I added since last build).

Let me first try to explain how I use it. Basically I have an tree (origination from some external -xml- files). I wish to display data from that tree. However depending on the actual place in the tree the data has to be drawn differently. (Using completely different dialogs).

So what I started to create was a static map. This map holds as key the tree "location" ("regexified" to something like "a * c d" - spaces denote branching). And as value the correct dialog should be pointed to.

The first idea was to simply use pointers to dialog screens. (And then the function that looks up the variable simply executes the dialog screen). However this resulted into the error shown above.

Now I started using an intermediate proxy function, where the function just creates the dialog screen and calls it. And the static map just holds a pointer to this function. Something like:

```
int AskGUIFn::GenStd(const GMProject::pTree& tOut, const GMProject::pTree& tIn) const {
    std::unique_ptr<MW::GenStd> box(new MW::GenStd(&tOut, &tIn));
    return box->exec();
}
```

However this seems very verbose (not only do I have to create all the modal windows, but I have to add another proxy function for each dialog screen). Is there a cleaner way to do this? I'd like to prevent using proxy functions?

Comment: I believe the answer to the question in your title is no, for the reason given in the error message. I'm wondering why wouldn't you just make a factory that produces the dialogs based on the requested type?

Comment: @kenrogers well the problem is I like to use the qt designer to create the dialog interface..

Comment: That's fine. You can call "new MyCustomDialogX(..." on a designer created dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static QWidgets are not possible - the QApplication object must be created before the QWidget. Also, the undefined initialization and destruction order of static variables would cause troubles. Also note that you should always pass a parent to a modal dialog in case you have other windows visible (e.g. a main window), otherwise window stacking will show annoying behavior on some platforms (modal dialogs behind disabled windows etc.). Like kenrogers I would suggest to use a factory function like:

```
QDialog* createDialogForNodeType( const QString& type, ...tree data, QWidget* parent );
```